# Need to avoid validation on not displayed fields under a panelgroup

Tags: jsf-2

I have two panel group and only one panel is displayed at any time using JQuery. There are multiple fields under each panel group which have required="true" attribute. My question is how to avoid validation on not displayed fields. Currently all the not displayed fields are get validated and the navigation get stopped.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the flag for hidden panelGroup then use the same flag variables in the place of hidden panel fileds.
For Example :
Use this

> required="#{managedBean.hiddenPanelGroupFlag}"

instead of

> required="true"

in you hidden panel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my panelgroup hiding and display depending on a value from a dropdown.

Comment: Add <a4j:support  event="onchange" reRender=
"panelGroupId"> in your dropdown and Use the same panelGroup rendered conditions in your required attribute of all fileds. Hope this will resolve your problem.